# UIView: Draw at double the size

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a UIView with a dynamically generated graphic context. Its normal size is 100x100, but it can be scaled up to 200x200, so I want its size to be actually 200x200 in order to appear nicely and not blurred however it is displayed.

How can always draw it 200x200 in drawRect, being it displayed at a size of 100 or at a size of 200? If I'm showing it at 100x100, the rect passed to drawRect is smaller than the area I need to draw into.

My code:

```
 - (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // prevent the drawings to be flipped
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, rect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height), [UIImage imageNamed:@"actionBg.png"].CGImage);

    // generate the overlay
    if ([self isActive] == NO && self.fullDelay != 0) { // TODO: remove fullDelay check!
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0);
        CGContextRef overlayCtx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        int segmentSize = (rect.size.height / [self fullDelay]);

        for (int i=0; i<[self fullDelay]; i++) {
            float alpha = 0.9 - (([self fullDelay] * 0.1) - (i * 0.1));
            [[UIColor colorWithRed:120.0/255.0 green:14.0/255.0 blue:14.0/255.0 alpha:alpha] setFill];

            if (currentDelay > i) {
                CGRect r = CGRectMake(0, i * segmentSize, rect.size.width, segmentSize);
                CGContextFillRect(overlayCtx, r);
            }
            [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.3] setFill];
            CGRect line = CGRectMake(0, (i * segmentSize) + segmentSize - 1 , rect.size.width, 1);
            CGContextFillRect(overlayCtx, line);
        }

        UIImage *overlay = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIImage *overlayMasked = [TDUtilities maskImage:overlay withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:@"actionMask.png"]];

        // prevent the drawings to be flipped
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, rect.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);

        // put the overlay
        CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, rect, overlayMasked.CGImage);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeNormal);

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    // prevent the drawings to be flipped
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, rect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);


    // draw the delay symbol
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, rect, [UIImage imageNamed:@"delaySymbol.png"].CGImage);

    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, 0.8);
    // draw the symbol
    NSString *imgName = [K_ACTION_IMAGES objectAtIndex:[self actionType]];
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, rect, [UIImage imageNamed:imgName].CGImage);

    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, 1);

    // draw the delay number
    imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", [self fullDelay]];
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, rect, [UIImage imageNamed:imgName].CGImage);

    // draw the priority number
    imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", [self actionType]];
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(32, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height), [UIImage imageNamed:imgName].CGImage);
}
```

Comment: How are you scaling it up?  Are you changing the `frame` or `bounds` of the view?  Or are you setting the view's `transform`?

Comment: Have you tried setting the view's `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`?  You can do it in code or in your xib.  Does that give you the result you want?

Comment: partially! the images are drawn ok, but the dynamic part is blurry. I updated the question with the code

Answer (score 0):

Have you called setNeedsDisplay method for you view after setting its frame